# Looping with glm function in R

Tags: r, glm

So I'm just trying to do some pretty simple stuff using the `glm` command.
I have a data frame which has 10 columns with different names and data. I then just need to do something like this:

```
variables <- c("reponse_var", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9")

for (variable in variables) {
    reg <- glm(response_var ~ variable, data = df, family = binomial(link = logit))
    summary(reg)
```

So basically it should just use the `glm` function on each single variable, and then print out the output. But this just doesn't work. The output is:

```
variable lengths differ (found for 'variable')
```

I thought that since the `data = df` it already knows which data frame it should take the data from, and usually it is enough to just write the name of the column in the `glm` function. But when doing this with for loops, well, this is what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to pack `response_var` and `variable` into a `formula()` object, and then feed *that* into the regression.
I think the error here is that you are feeding string objects into the `glm()`.